# how do you update a R model, choosing the covariate with a list O vector with names of covariate

Tags: r

```
ac0=c("WEIGHT","PREMENO","SMOKE") #this is the vector with names
ac1=glm(FRACTURE~PRIORFRAC+AGE+HEIGHT+MOMFRAC+RATERISK, data=glow, family='binomial')
ac2=update(ac1, formula.=~.+ac0[1])
```

Error is this:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = FRACTURE ~ PRIORFRAC + AGE + HEIGHT +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'ac0[1]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create the formula and then pass it to update:

```
mF <- formula(paste(". ~ . +", ac0[1]))
update(ac1, mF)
```